# Radio button binding in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have one group of 4 radio buttons of which on page load i have to preselect that radio button which matches the ng-model data i have defined the data to be matched in value tag & ng-value tag but its not working.

```
A<input type="radio" name="export" value="A" ng-model="item.exportsCat" />
B<input type="radio" name="export" value="B" ng-model="item.exportsCat" />
C<input type="radio" name="export" value="C" ng-model="item.exportsCat" />
D<input type="radio" name="export" value="D" ng-model="item.exportsCat" />
```

on page load ng-model="item.exportsCat" has a value of 'C'.
so i want C radio button to be selected.

Comment: you don't have to define the `value` attributes in your input fields at all. replace them with `ng-value`. And then check whither `$scope.item.exportCat` is set to value `C`

Comment: @Sage, `value` attribute is also valid. This is not the problem.

Comment: @Zanon, I didn't say it is invalid I said it is less useful than using `ng-value` and hence as `ng-value` is being defined, using `value` attribute won't achieve anything

Comment: @Rohan, you need to provide more info. As you described, your example works fine. See this working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JfuFT0GAu2qX4rMedjBg?p=preview) example and provide an updated version that shows your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to init your variable in your controller like:
`$scope.item.exportsCat = 'C';`

Answer (score 0):

Well thats works for me:

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('ControllerFirst',function($scope){
  $scope.item = {
      exportsCat: 'D'
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerFirst">
   <input type="radio" name="export" value="A" ng-model="item.exportsCat" />A
            <input type="radio" name="export" value="B" ng-model="item.exportsCat" />B
            <input type="radio" name="export" value="D" ng-model="item.exportsCat" />D
            <input type="radio" name="export" value="C" ng-model="item.exportsCat" />C
</div>
```

And here its my jsfiddle whit this works:

https://jsfiddle.net/javierif/ckp27a25/